# Laravel VentureCraft revisionable not working on Laravel 5.5 when updating model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, versioning, revisionable

I used this package called [revisionable](https://github.com/VentureCraft/revisionable) so I tried to add it to my `package.json` and run the migration and everything worked fine.

But when I try to create a record and then update them it doesn't fill out the revisions table?

I am using `"venturecraft/revisionable": "^1.28",` and **Laravel 5.5**

Here is my code in my **model**

So here is what I have done in my **model**

```
use Venturecraft\Revisionable\Revisionable;
use Venturecraft\Revisionable\RevisionableTrait;

class AnalysisRequest extends Revisionable
{
    use SoftDeletes;
    use RevisionableTrait;

    protected $revisionEnabled = true;
    protected $revisionCleanup = true;
    protected $historyLimit = 100; //Stop tracking revisions after 500 changes have been made.

    protected $dontKeepRevisionOf = array(
        'client_id', 'service_id', 'categories_id', 'methodologies_id', 'current_version', 'due_date'
    );

    protected $keepRevisionOf = array(
        'sample_description',
        'special_instruction',
        'status',
        'rushable'
    );
```

When did I did wrong?

Can someone shed some light for me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your class should be extending `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`

Comment: I did it. But still not working.

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: I use laravel 5.5

Answer (score 1):

For those who uses this [package](https://github.com/VentureCraft/revisionable) out there. There is no problem with the new versions of **Laravel**.

The problem is by using the **eloquent** methods of laravel especially with the **update** method.

So instead of updating a **model** like this example below.

```
$analysis_request = AnalysisRequest::where('id', $input['id'])->update([
            'client_id' => $input['client_id'],
            'sample_description' => $input['sample_description'],
            'special_instruction' => $input['special_instruction'],
            'rushable' => $input['rushable'],
            'status' => 'for_testing'
        ]);
```

You have to do it this way in order to make revisions of the **model**. See below

```
$analysis_request = AnalysisRequest::where('id', $input['id'])->first();
        $analysis_request->client_id = $input['client_id'];
        $analysis_request->sample_description = $input['sample_description'];
        $analysis_request->special_instruction = $input['special_instruction'];
        $analysis_request->status = 'for_testing';
        $analysis_request->save();
```

As you can see I used the `first()` method to fetch my model and update it using `save()` You can't use the `save()` method if you don't use the `first()`.

Reference [link](https://github.com/VentureCraft/revisionable/issues/255) of the issue in github.

I know it's hard to do it like that way. But for now you will be forced to if you want to make your life easier when creating revisions instead of manually doing it on your own. But hey it still depends on your case.

I hope the author makes a fix on this soon in the next release.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I did some digging on this, and it looks like it's a limitation of the package (it doesn't include the `updating` event - ref: `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasEvents.php`).

You can try to "override" the trait function and add the event yourself though:

```
class AnalysisRequest extends Model {
    use RevisionableTrait {
        bootRevisionableTrait as protected unused;
    }

    ....

    //Override trait function
    public static function bootRevisionableTrait() {
        static::saving(function ($model) {
            $model->preSave();
        });
        static::saved(function ($model) {
            $model->postSave();
        });
        static::created(function($model){
            $model->postCreate();
        });
        static::deleted(function ($model) {
            $model->preSave();
            $model->postDelete();
        });

        //Add in the update events
        static::updating(function ($model) {
            $model->preSave();
        });
        static::updated(function ($model) {
            $model->postSave();
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: I tried to update the model but it is still not working.